# Building an array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a loop in JavaScript that pulls data from a SharePoint list and what I'm trying to do is use the caleander.js plug in to build a calendar view of these events from this list.

Where I've gotten stuck is that the plug in accepts and array and I'm trying to build that array dynamically from the list data.

e.g.

```
function getSuperRegionNames(xData, status) 
{

    var events = "";
    alert("entered loop")

    //Iterates through each row and returns information - Populates the "Super Region Full Name" dropdown with values from the Super Region list
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() 
    {  
        var ID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
        var Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        var AssignedTo = $(this).attr("ows_AssignedTo");
        var Description = $(this).attr("ows_Body");

        var aStartdate = $(this).attr("ows_DueDate");

        var Status = $(this).attr("ows_Status");
        var Priority = $(this).attr("ows_Priority");

        var aDueDate = $(this).attr("ows_DueDate");
                var bDueDate = moment(aDueDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
                var bYear = moment(aDueDate).year();
                var bMonth = moment(aDueDate).month();
                var bDate = moment(aDueDate).date();
        var select = "<a class='btn btn-s btn-success'  style='width:150px' target='_blank' href='registrationselect.aspx?id="+ID+"'>View Detail</a>";

        //events.push({'Date': new Date(bYear, bMonth, bDate), 
        //          'Title': Title, 
        //          'Link': ID, 
        //          'Status': Status, 
        //          'AssignedTo': AssignedTo, 
        //          'Priority': Priority},
        //          });


        var appendThis = "{'Date': " + new Date(bYear, bMonth, bDate) + ", 'Title': " + Title +", 'Link': " + ID + ", 'Status': " + Status + ", 'AssignedTo': " + AssignedTo + ", 'Priority': " + Priority + "},";
        events = events + appendThis;
        alert(appendThis);          

        $("#results").append("<tr style='border-bottom:thin gray solid' align='middle'>" +
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+ID+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+Title+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+AssignedTo+"</td>"  +                                         
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+Description+"</td>"  +   
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+bDueDate+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+Status+"</td>" +
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+Priority+"</td>"  +                                         
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+bYear+"</td>"  + 
        "<td align='left' style='padding:10px'>"+select+"</td>"  + 
        "</tr>");
    });

    alert(events);
    var loadEvents = [
        events
    ];
    var settings={}       
    var element = document.getElementById('caleandar');
    caleandar(element, loadEvents, settings);

}
```

You can see in that last section I'm trying to take a string and "magically" make an array out of it but I'm clearly on the wrong track with that idea.

Any thoughts on how I can build an array from a list of values as I loop through the list?

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a dynamic array by many ways, one of the easiest way is below:

```
    var arr = [];
    arr[arr.length] = { 'Date' : (new Date(bYear, bMonth, bDate)),
'Title': Title,
'Link': ID,
'Status': Status,
'AssignedTo': AssignedTo,
'Priority': Priority };
```

Put, "arr = [];" outside of loop and rest code in the loop and check your array is ready.